# Understanding concept of structs

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I want to know what is the difference between

```
int a;
```

and

```
struct node{
  int a;
};

struct node b;
```

Are they the same?

Comment: Basic thing! int is an integer. struct is a structure

Comment: The second snippet is being reviewed behind the [door on the right](http://i.imgur.com/7OZfY8T.png).  Declaring a struct with just one member is not generally useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not same. Operations permitted by language on `a` and `b` are different as their types are different. When they contain same bit patterns, interpretation of those bit patterns may be different.

Compiler may take different path to return an `int` vs `struct node` from a function or while passing them as function argument.

Essentially `a` and `b.a` possess same behavior. Compiler may sometime choose to optimize single member structs with the type of member.

**Differences**
1. Compile time: Type of a and type of b are different
2. Compile time: a = 42 (OK), b = 42 (Error)
3. Run time: Compiler may choose to use different strategies while copying a and b to a different variable of same type.
4. [section 6.7.2.1 in the C99 standard](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.2.1.html) says ***There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning***., which means `sizeof a` is allowed to be not equal to the `sizeof b`

**Extra notes**
Single member structs are almost always not required except in cases when
1. Other members are conditionally compiled out. (To keep the code manageable)
2. When you plan to pass an array as function parameter, return an array from a function or copy array using assignation operator.
3. Restrict operations. [For example you don't want emp id to be added, subtracted etc but assignation is OK]

Answer (score 2):

No, they are **not same**.

`int a;` --> a variable named `a` of type integer.

`struct node b;` --> a variable named `b` of type `struct node`.

here, the struct contains only `int a` but that's not the case *always*. These two variables are

1. indeed of different data types.
2. representations are different.
3. access methods are different.

Comment: dear @downvoter, please let me know the error in this answer by putting a comment.

Comment: Don't care for anonymous downvoter and share what you think is right unless explained as incorrect by somebody else.

Comment: @MohitJain well, right you are sir, but sometimes it's really demotivating.

Comment: I have seen you active on SO. Don't care for others, do what you think is good. You are doing a great job already. I hope this is motivating :) Moreover I have got 1 more downvote than you did (shy)

Comment: @MohitJain thank you sir. I'll try to do my best. :-) actually when this `hit-and-run` downvote starts appearing in _almost_ every post, then sometimes I think my approach is not right...maybe..who knows...

Answer (score 0):

As per your example both are same. But structure is mainly used for accessing the more than one variable using the common variable name.

```
 struct node {
         int a;
         float b;
         char c;
 };
 struct node b;
```

So now using the variable b we can access the three different data types. So this is the main advantage of structure.

Accessing the structure as normal variable. b.a;
If you are using the pointer then this will be b->a. Note you have to allocate the memory for that.

Comment: Please... answers should provide formatted code. BTW downvote is not from me.